# I'm right about the time complexity on these situations?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, time-complexity, pseudocode

I'm a little doubtful about the correctness of my assumptions when analyzing the time complexity of code like this. In this piece of code array.length() is considered as a linear complexity function. This last detail is important, the original exercise considered it was just a constant stored value, but I'm wondering what should happen if not):

```
void printPairs(int[] array) {
   for (int i = 0; i < array.length(), i++) {
       for (int j = 0; j < array.length(), j++){
          print(array[i], array[j])
       }
   }
}
```

So, if array.length was a variable inside array, like in java, all this thing would be just O(N^2). But what if array.length() is a function? His implementation should be linear...then...at first I tought it should become a O(N^4) code, but thinking better about it now I think is just O(N^3). But also I think that may be I'm wrong with both assumptions and it keep being O(N^2).

Can someone correct me? Thanks!

Comment: Ehm, my reasoning was that, the code with array.length() function descomposed would become like this "for" structure:

for ...
    for ... (first .length())
    for ...
       for ... ((second .length()))

Thats why I tought, seeing 3 levels of for identation, that it was O(N^3). What is exactly the part which is bad in my reasoning?

Comment: For an array of integers, there is no "strlen"-like mechanism and the length is stored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`j < array.length()` is called `array.length()*array.length()` times.

If `array.length()` is O(1), then O(N^2).  (e.g. C++)

If `array.length()` is O(N), then O(N^3).  (e.g. C `strlen()` although code may optimize it back to O(1))

Comment: Thanks! I was interested in the unoptimized case, because I justed forced the case in my mind to try to understand what would happen purely from a theoric point of view on that situation. So it was O(N^3) then. Your way of reasoning on the first line help me to think better about this also, because I was thinking on it in a more visual for-nested way.

Answer (score 1):

Chances are that the compiler can do a simple optimisation:

```
void printPairs(int[] array) {
   int n = array.length();
   for (int i = 0; i < n, i++) {
       for (int j = 0; j < n, j++){
          print(array[i], array[j])
       }
   }
}
```

And that is O(N^2)